# How using bin2d from ggplot2 distinguish two data sets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames a and b

```
a)  
x y z  
1 2 a  
3 4 a

b)  
x y z  
2 3 b  
4 5 b
```

After merging them with merge() I am trying to visualize them on the same graph using bin2d from ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y))+stat_bin2d(bins=30)
```

is there a way to distinguish which region describes data set `a` and which one is from `b`?
Maybe using different colors for each data or some contour?
Thanks!

Comment: How would you deal with bins that contain elements of both data sets?

Comment: for example they will be on the intersection of two contours (one for a and second for b), or the would have color in-between

Comment: hmm, using facets I know how to put two graphs side by side but I want to have two graphs in one plot (with one x and y axis)

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,3), y=c(2,4), z=c("a","a"))
b <- data.frame(x=c(2,4), y=c(3,5), z=c("b","b")) 

# merge
df <- rbind(a, b)

# plot with z (a or b) as the color
qplot(x, y, z, data=df, color=z) + stat_bin2d(bins=30)
```

Comment: Yes, I was doing the same but it does not work until you change color=z to fill=z, now more or less works ;)

Comment: Yes, calling via ggplot() requires the fill aesthetic vs. the above qplot call.